# How to check pdf file is password protected?

Tags: java, pdf

How to check pdf file is password protected or not in java?
I know of several tools/libraries that can do this but I want to know if this is possible with just program in java.

Comment: you answered your own question. Use opensource libs like itext and write a java program to test.

Comment: I suppose some of these tools/libraries were written in pure `java` (while some others could be written in other languages, but it's not the matter of subject), weren't they? :) If so, why can't you write your own implementation of such password check?

Comment: As @aga pointed out, it obviously is possible to do that in Java. Thus, your question most likely misses some additional requirement you did not mention. Please explain your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

you can use PDFBox:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

code example :

```
try
{
    document = PDDocument.load( yourPDFfile );

    if( document.isEncrypted() )
    {
      //ITS ENCRYPTED!
    }
}
```

using maven?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also helpful to get the page count using `getNumberOfPages()`

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

As per mkl's comment below this answer, it seems that there are two types of PDF structures permitted by the specs: (1) Cross-referenced tables (2) Cross-referenced Streams. The following solution only addresses the first type of structure. This answer needs to be updated to address the second type.

====

All of the answers provided above refer to some third party libraries which is what the OP is already aware of. The OP is asking for native Java approach. My answer is yes, you can do it but it will require a lot of work.

It will require a two step process:

**Step 1**: **Figure out if the PDF is encrypted**

As per Adobe's PDF 1.7 [specs](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) (page number 97 and 115), if the trailer record contains the key "\Encrypted", the pdf is encrypted (the encryption could be simple password protection or RC4 or AES or some custom encryption). Here's a sample code:

```
    Boolean isEncrypted = Boolean.FALSE;
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Resources/1.pdf"));
        //Convert the binary bytes to String. Caution, it can result in loss of data. But for our purposes, we are simply interested in the String portion of the binary pdf data. So we should be fine.
        String pdfContent = new String(byteArray);
        int lastTrailerIndex = pdfContent.lastIndexOf("trailer");
        if(lastTrailerIndex >= 0 && lastTrailerIndex < pdfContent.length()) {
            String newString =  pdfContent.substring(lastTrailerIndex, pdfContent.length());
            int firstEOFIndex = newString.indexOf("%%EOF");
            String trailer = newString.substring(0, firstEOFIndex);
            if(trailer.contains("/Encrypt"))
                isEncrypted = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        //Do nothing
    }
```

**Step 2**: **Figure out the encryption type**

This step is more complex. I don't have a code sample yet. But here is the algorithm:

1. Read the value of the key "/Encrypt" from the trailer as read in the step 1 above. E.g. the value is 288 0 R.
2. Look for the bytes "288 0 obj". This is the location of the "encryption dictionary" object in the document. This object boundary ends at the string "endobj".
3. Look for the key "/Filter" in this object. The "Filter" is the one that identifies the document's security handler. If the value of the "/Filter" is "/Standard", the document uses the built-in password-based security handler.

If you just want to know whether the PDF is encrypted without worrying about whether the encryption is in form of owner / user password or some advance algorithms, you don't need the step 2 above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work if the pdf uses cross reference streams instead of tables.

Comment: @mkl Can you please elaborate with maybe an example? I would be happy to update my answer if needed. The goal is to help the community with the most efficient answer.

Comment: A pdf which uses cross reference streams does not have a trailer as sought by your code. Instead the trailer entries are added to the cross reference stream dictionary.

Comment: @mkl, can you please attach an example PDF that uses xref streams and not xref tables? The specs clearly say that encryption information is stored in the trailer dictionary.

Comment: As I'm currently on a smart phone only, I don't have my sample files at hand. But simply look at the specification ISO 32000-1, section 7.5.8 "Cross-Reference  Streams": *Cross-reference  streams  are stream  objects (see  7.3.8, "Stream  Objects"),  and contain  a dictionary  and  a  data stream. Each cross-reference  stream  contains  the  information  equivalent  to the cross-reference  table (see 7.5.4, "Cross-Reference  Table")  and  trailer  (see  7.5.5, "File Trailer")  for  one  cross-reference  section.*

Comment: As an example, you might take the [New York State Department of Motor Vehicles 2002 Carrier's Annual Review of Employee's Driving Record unter Article 19-A](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/ds872.pdf).

Comment: @mkl, thank you for your explanation with examples. I have put this information in the answer until I find a solution for the cross-reference stream structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) pdf API we can identify the password protected PDF.

**Example :**

```
    try {
            new PdfReader("C:\\Password_protected.pdf");            
        } catch (BadPasswordException e) {
            System.out.println("PDF is password protected..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: iText is under AGPL licence. So, I suggest to use PDFBox.

Comment: The reader is not sufficient enough as the pdf is never opened. Second line should be 
    new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));

Answer (score 0):

You can validate pdf, i.e it can be readable, writable by using Itext.

Following is the code snippet,

```
boolean isValidPdf = false;
try {
    InputStream tempStream = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/pdffile.pdf"));
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempStream);
    isValidPdf = reader.isOpenedWithFullPermissions();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isValidPdf = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct how to do it in java answer is per @vhs.

However in any application by far the simplest is to use very lightweight pdfinfo tool to filter the encryption status and here using windows cmd I can instantly get a report that two different copies of the same file are encrypted

```
>forfiles /m *.pdf /C "cmd /c echo @file &pdfinfo @file|find /i \"Encrypted\""

"Certificate (9).pdf"
Encrypted:      no

"ds872 source form.pdf"
Encrypted:      AES 128-bit

"ds872 filled form.pdf"
Encrypted:      AES 128-bit

"How to extract data from a particular area in a PDF file - Stack Overflow.pdf"
Encrypted:      no

"Test.pdf"
Encrypted:      no

>
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution:

1) Install PDF Parser http://www.pdfparser.org/

2) Edit Parser.php in this section:

```
if (isset($xref['trailer']['encrypt'])) {
echo('Your Allert message');
exit();}
```

3)In your .php form post ( ex. upload.php) insert this:

```
for the first require  '...yourdir.../vendor/autoload.php';
```

then write this function:

```
function pdftest_is_encrypted($form) {
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile($form);
}
```

and then call the function

```
pdftest_is_encrypted($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"]);
```

This is all, if you'll try to load a PDF with password the system return an error "Your Allert message"

Comment: Your answer is for PHP, but the question asks for a Java solution.